# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Service' error in consuming web Services in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem when calling  web Services in  ASP.net MVC , I do the following

add the web service by add service reference to solution, and I include the service.cs file to the solution also, but when I try to create object in home controller ,  I have the following error

Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'Service' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

can any one help me please

thanks

Comment: Post your configuration file(s), please.

Comment: I run  svcutil.exe utility to generate the code files that will be later used in client consumer application so I have output.config file I copy the code in this file to web.config file below is the configuration file

Comment: thanks Mate but how to check name space , I added the web service to my solution with name Service1, and add the configuration to web.config file so where is the problem please

Comment: I'm a little confused - first you say you added the service to your application via "Add Service Reference", then you say you used SVCUTIL to generate the files for use by the client.  I was able to do it both ways and connect to the service both times successfully - can you post the code you used or the steps you took that gave you the error above?

Comment: ok Tim , when I add the following service to my asp.net mvc application http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx , I add this service by right click to the solution and add service reference

Comment: , then I create the class and configuration file by run SVCUTIL to the service so I have  Weather.cs and output.config files, after that I add Weather.cs file to the solution , then I go to home controllor and all the following code      var x=new WeatherHttpGetClient();

Comment: and i have the following error Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'WeatherHttpGet' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

Comment: now, did you understand me Tim, and how can I solve the problem please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things going on here.  First, you're using SVCUTIL to generate a proxy and configuration settings for a non-WCF service - .asmx is legacy.  I was able to generate a proxy and config settings, but to overcome the error you got you need to call one of the overloaded versions of `WeatherHttpClient`.

I'm not 100% sure, but this is what I think based on what I observed.

The reason is because there are two endpoints defined in the configuration file (one for SOAP 1.1 and one for SOAP 1.2), and since both endpoints are named there is no default endpoint to choose from.

When I used `var x = new WeatherHttpClient(new BasicHttpBinding("WeatherSoap"), new EndpointAddress("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"));` I was able to create the proxy just fine.

However, when I called `GetCityForecastByZip` I got the following error:

`Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/WeatherHttpGet/GetCityForecastByZIPRequest.`

So then I used WSDL.exe to generate the proxy a la .ASMX style.  I included that in my project, and the following code returned a result (after including a reference to `System.Web.Services` - I was using a console app):

```
var x = new Weather();

ForecastReturn result = x.GetCityForecastByZip("91504");`
```

I would suggest for simplicity using WSDL.exe to generate the proxy for your service, as it seems to be simpler.

I will also add that I've done very little MVC, but I don't think this is an MVC issue.  I hope this helps you.